# Prolog existence_error for predicate in generated prolog file

Tags: prolog

I'm having a problem with a program that I'm writing. The program takes an input and generates a prolog program based on it. It generates something like this:

```
test(A):-condA(A),condB(A).
condA(val).
condB(val).
```

My problem is that sometimes, there is no condB(val), or condB anywhere in the program, except in the above definition of test. In that case, I got existence_error for condB, when I try to ask test(val), for example. Is there a way to add something to the prolog program that would define condB as false for all values of it's argument?

I'm sorry if this is stupid question, as I'm new to prolog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell the prolog processor that `condB/1` is dynamic:

```
:-dynamic condB/1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question is simple.

```
condB(_):-fail.
```

the symbol '_' is free variable.

Comment: If you generate the other definitions with specific values before this definition, then the conditions succeed for all arguments before line with this code.